# How to determine if an RFID system supports reading multiple tags at once?

Tags: rfid

In [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/11062/319) the following is stated:

> Most RFID protocols include singulation so that if you put dozens of
>   RFID tags in front of it, and then turn on the RFID reader, it can
>   read the correct serial number from each and every tag.

How can you determine what protocols and devices do or do not support singulation? When performing searches on RFID singulation most of the results are related to the theoretical side and not what components or protocols support it. Are there any more proper terms to be using for this type of "feature" in RFID?

For some context, I am looking for a way to read multiple passive objectives that may or may not be stacked on top of each other.

Answer (score 3):

Look for "anti-collision" and "multi-access" instead if "singulation". Common methods/protocols are:

- Slotted ALOHA (a form of TDMA)
- Adaptive Binary Tree
- Slotted Terminal Adaptive Collection (STAC) ... similar to ALOHA
- EPC UHF Class I Gen 2

Answer (score 0):

Reading some rfid manuals I've come with the following:

> EM4100 compatible transponders do not have collision avoidance
>   algorithms only one card can be scanned within the range of the reader
>   at any one time.

EM4100 is one of the most popular transmission methods, so I'd say most RFID readers are not singulation-capable.