# RFID Multiplexing

Tags: multiplexer, rfid, mfrc522

I'm planning on doing some project just for fun and education purposes. My project involves RFID technology. I don't have much experience on this topic, however I've been doing research on it and I kind of understand the way it works and how to be implemented using Arduino (which is something I plan on using).

- *Is there any RFID Reader Module with MUX integrated?*

I have found many artifacts that may be useful, although the price is pretty expensive and I only need something pretty basic. As for now I have only encountered this module, I don't know if any of you have worked with **RFID NFC Pepper C1 MUX UART/USB**.

The problem with this module is that, it limits up to 8 external antennas, but I want to know if there's a possible alternative on using any other RFID Reader Module and manipulate it in order to expand the number of ports. I have read about many other types of RFID Readers and the most common one is the **MFRC522**, although this one already includes an antenna on its own module. I have also read other topics here in StackExchange about using an ordinary MUX connected through an Arduino and the RFID Reader, but not sure if that's an optimal way of doing it. Instead I was thinking on something more centralized on pure RFID reading as the **RFID Pepper C1 MUX**.

Also I have seen that other people have been able to connect **TRF7960A** Module to an Arduino to make it work and also implement Multiplexing on it.

Hopefully you can help me on finding alternatives on how to accomplish this through a more economical way. I'm open to learning more about electronics, so I'll be glad to hear you.

Sources I've looked into:

- [Arduino RFID Multiplexer Antennas](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/480722/arduino-rfid-multiplexer-antennas)
- [RFID Pepper C1 MUX Module](https://eccel.co.uk/product/pepper-c1-mux-uart/)
- [More about RFID Multiplexing](https://www.rfid-wiot-search.com/times-7-an-introduction-to-multiplexers-4151)
- [TRF7960A MUX Video](https://youtu.be/16VFU9n8VO4)

Comment: Rodolfo Contreras - Hi, FYI asking several questions within one topic is discouraged here. Questions must be [reasonably scoped](/help/dont-ask) and asking for product recommendations is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You might be lucky and find a site member who wants to address all the points in your question in one answer, but IMHO it is a "big ask". If you could [edit] your question (without invalidating the partial answer you already have) to limit its scope and avoid asking for recommendations, that would help. Also you can check our [tour] & [help] to see more site rules. Thanks.

Comment: what's an `ordinary MUX`?

Comment: Perfect, I'll edit my question.

And I refer to ordinary MUX because there are some companies that sell RFID Multiplexers, but pretty expensive, talking about +$1000 USD I don't know if those contain some special features other than just MUX 1 to 8.

Answer (score 0):

The RFID you are referring to is 13.58MHz. This means you’ll need coaxial cable and connectors between your antennas and reader hardware. The cost of this as well as the circuitry to multiplex it will exceed the cost of simply having multiple reader boards with their own pcb antenna.

Comment: So, for a starting test, you would recommend on using multiple common RFID Readers such as the MFRC522 Module? And yeah, I knew I would need coaxial cable for my antennas, they even sell the RFID Mux Module Antennas with their corresponding coaxial cable

Comment: The goal of learning technology and asking for technical advice on an unfeasible approach might be rewarding to you but the cost of an RF connector pair will be greater than the MFRC522 board for <$1 in volume. So perhaps if you can focus your design specs to include budget, learning experience and overall purpose, then the design spec questions will put your goals in better focus and perspective.

Comment: Yes, I'm open to spend money just not that much as I've seen on some products. Because I've encountered RFID MUX over 500 USD. Difference on the one I present on my post, I'm just wondering if someone has already worked with that particular MUX module or if someone has any other workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You may try CMOS RF switches as  relays for signals and make your own general purpose mux on PCB. Go for the most common (esp those usually used as repair parts) but feasible model for the lowest price.

But RF PCB design is a deep rabbit hole, that's why they are so expensive.